# dyld: Symbol not found: _rb_ary_new_from_values When trying to run foreman start

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, psych

I am receiving the following error when trying to run "foreman start" to execute my rails file.

```
dyld: Symbol not found: _rb_ary_new_from_values
  Referenced from: /Users/paulbattisson/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/psych-2.0.5/lib/psych.bundle
  Expected in: flat namespace
```

If I run rails s then the app starts fine however I am wanting to use the following Procfile:

```
web: bundle exec rackup config.ru -p $PORT
resque: env TERM_CHILD=1 bundle exec rake resque:work
```

So that I can utilise resque. Any help is much ppreciated. I have tried bundle install to see if that resolves the issue but it seems not. I am managed rvm via JewelryBox and using Rails 4.1.1 with Ruby 2.1.1

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The solution seems to have been reinstalling foreman using

```
gem install foreman
```